# Unable to delete hover transparency on share button

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I know this might be a really simple question by I have been stuck with it for a couple hours.

I have some share buttons n my website https://honeststrategy.com/#share-btn

I have them in black and I want them to stay completely black when you hover over them but for some reason is making it a little bit transparent on hover and I am not able to avoid this behavior or find the code creating it in the developers' tool console of google chrome.

I have tried all this but nothing seems to work:

```
.a2a_button_facebook path:hover{
opacity:1 !important;
color:black !important;
fill:black !important;
}

.addtoany_list.a2a_kit_size_32 a:hover{
opacity:1 !important;
color:black !important;
fill:black !important;
}

.a2a_svg a2a_s__default .a2a_s_twitter .a2a_img_text:hover{
opacity:1 !important;
color:black !important;
fill:black !important;
}

.a2a_svg svg:hover{
opacity:1 !important;
color:black !important;
fill:black !important;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks a lot and once again sorry if it is something really obvious but I am kind of stuck in here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.addtoany_list a:hover img, .addtoany_list a:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!